# Application specific MySQL table Structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a question about my DB table structure. I want to know if i'm on the right track or if I have missed a good alternative. Here is the case:

To make it easy to read, I haven't pasted the full contents as my question is only about the structure.

2 tables:

1: id (AI), task
2: id, name, task

Table 1 presents dynamic check-boxes which can be altered by an admin panel so the contents would be like this

1 task1
2 task2
5 task5

(3 & 4 are missing cause the administrator deleted those records).

In table number two are the people who should do the tasks from table 1. And the goal is that the tasks wich are not checked will be displayed.

So the contents of table 2 would be:

1 Name1 1,5 
2 Name2 1,2 
3 Name3 1,2,5

The numbers in table 2 represent the checked boxes from table 1. So with a query i can compare the numbers from table 2 with the id's from table 1 and display the missing ids as "todo".

In my opinion this looks very overdone, and there must be an easier way to create dynamic options which can be compared and stored as a todo.

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use basic structure for many-to-many relationship:

```
tasks                users            user_tasks
+----+-----------+   +----+-------+   +---------+---------+
| id | name      |   | id | name  |   | user_id | task_id |
+----+-----------+   +----+-------+   +---------+---------+
|  1 | Buy milk  |   |  1 | John  |   |       1 |       2 |
|  2 | Get drunk |   |  2 | Tim   |   |       3 |       2 |
|  3 | Have fun  |   |  3 | Steve |   |       2 |       4 |
|  4 | Go home   |   +----+-------+   |       3 |       4 |
+----+-----------+                    +---------+---------+
```

And you can fetch unassigned tasks using following query:

```
SELECT
    tasks.*
FROM
    tasks
LEFT JOIN
    user_tasks
    ON (tasks.id = user_tasks.task_id)
WHERE
    user_tasks.user_id IS NULL
```

You also can fetch users who have no assigned tasks:

```
SELECT
    users.*
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    user_tasks
    ON (users.id = user_tasks.user_id)
WHERE
    user_tasks.user_id IS NULL
```

Hope this will help you.